# python failing to cast a float to int

Tags: python, casting

I'm having a little problem to understand why python won't cast a float to an int. The following is a code snippet.

```
import time

now = time.time()
print type(now)
int(now)
print type(now)
```

And this is the result I get, I can't quite figure out why. Any ideas? Thanks in advance

```
<type 'float'>
<type 'float'>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to reassign `now` like so:

```
now = int(now)
```

The `int()` conversion does not operate in place - it merely returns the result of the conversion, which is why you need to reassign `now` to the new value.

As a general rule, **functions** return a new value, while **methods** operate in place. For the difference between functions and methods, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/155609/1907098).

Comment: Thanks a lot I couldn't quite understand why, now I do.

Comment: The important thing to remember here is that `int()` is not a C-style cast; it's the `int` constructor and it returns an integer object, so you gotta store that somewhere.

Comment: That explains why! I studied C till a couple of weeks ago. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

`int()` doesn't operate in-place. You still have to overwrite `now`:

```
now = int(now)
```

Although I'd just do it all at once:

```
now = int(time.time())
```

Answer (score 3):

You never set now to the int version

```
import time
now = time.time()
print type(now)
now = int(now) # set now to int version
print type(now)
```